# Can't not connect my print imz320 and motorola tc55, use bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I have problems with the connection of bluetooth because sometimes print and after not works!, I need restar the print Zebra im320 and reconnect and pair and this isn't stable..

```
public void pairPrinter()  {
     final UUID SerialPortServiceClass_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
     final BluetoothAdapter BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     final String PrinterBsid = "AC:3F:A4:18:B2:B0";
     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream sOut;
            BluetoothSocket socket;
            BA.cancelDiscovery();


            BluetoothDevice BD = BA.getRemoteDevice(PrinterBsid);
            try {
                socket = BD.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID);
                BD.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID);

                if (!socket.isConnected()) {
                   // Thread.sleep(2000);

                    socket.connect();
                    Thread.sleep(2000); // <-- WAIT FOR SOCKET
                }
                sOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                String cpclData = "! 0 200 200 210 1\r\n"
                        + "TEXT 4 0 30 40 This is a CPCL test.\r\n"
                        + "FORM\r\n";
                sOut.write(cpclData.getBytes());
                sOut.flush();
                sOut.close();

                socket.close();
                BA.cancelDiscovery();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

And this my logs

E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp﹕ onDiscoverServicesResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Connection timed out)

D/BluetoothService﹕ Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: AC:3F:A4:18:B2:B0 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

E/﹕ IOException

W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed

W/System.err: atandroid.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:465)

W/System.err﹕ atandroid.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:230)

W/System.err: atcom.example.msanchez.printzebra.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:73)

W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your code is calling twice the `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` API. This doesn't seem right.

Which device are you using to print on the iMZ320? I've done some test in the past with Android v4.1 and Android v4.4 and they've a different behaviour.

You can take a look at the [original discussion on Zebra developer's forum](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/message/82234#82234) for some guidance.

May be relevant to understand which Firmware version you're running on the printer, again, the Zebra developer's forum should help in this case.